# PowerShell CmdLet as Visual Studio External Tool

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell

I am attempting to add a PowerShell cmdlet as an external tool in Visual Studio 2010, but whenever I call the external tool I get:

> {foo} cannot be loaded because the
>   execution of scripts is disabled on
>   this system. Please see "get-help
>   about_signing" for more details.

I have already set my system's execution policy to 'RemoteSigned' (I also tried 'Bypass'), so why is this happening? I am fully able to run that same script if I open up a command line and call it via `powershell.exe path\to\script.ps1` (which is exactly what my external tool definition is calling).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you running on a x64 system?  If so, you have to set the execution for both x86 and x64 PowerShell.  You can also pass the ExecutionPolicy directly as a parameter to Powershell (2.0) via the command line:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "&{ foo }"
```

Comment: Nice one. You helped me out of a hole there :)